# Golang reading multiple fields from stdin line

Tags: go, split, scanf, stdin

```
$ echo "A 1 2 3 4" | go run test.go 
entire:  A
next field:  A
```

I need to read several lines from standard input that are like "A 1 2 3 4" (code does one line for now) and something goes wrong. `Scanln` should read the entire line and `Fields` should split it by newlines? Why does Scanln read only one word?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var line string
    fmt.Scanln(&line)
    fmt.Println("entire: ",line)
    for _,x := range strings.Fields(line) {
        fmt.Println("next field: ",x)
    }
}
```

---

```
$ echo "A 1 2 3 4" | go run test.go 
entire:  A
next field:  A
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var line string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line = scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println("Got line:", line)
        for _, x := range strings.Fields(line) {
            fmt.Println("next field: ",x)
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
$ printf "aa bb \n cc dd " | go run 1.go  
Got line: aa bb
next field:  aa
next field:  bb
Got line:  cc dd
next field:  cc
next field:  dd
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to store each input to a seperate variable you can try this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var a, b string
    var c int
    var r = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Fscanf(r, "%s %s %d", &a, &b, &c)
    fmt.Printf("%s %s %d", a, b, c)
}
```

It will give the following output:

```
//given input
w r 4
//output
w r 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I got mislead by another question's answer that said `Scanln` reads an entire line. No, Scanln is only a Scan that reads words (space separated strings) and as many as actual variables specified, but quits parsing on a newline. Its totally confusing what the readline equivalent would be in Go.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I was searching for the same thing and realized that we could improve to the explanation.

It was actually the comment from original poster @ArekBulskithat gave me the clue when he said

> Scanln is only a Scan that reads words (space separated strings) and as many as actual variables specified

Scanln() will read the entire line, but it only saves the number of strings equal to the number of variables in the parameters so for "A 1 2 3 4" `fmt.Scanln(&var1)` will only store "A" and `fmt.Scanln(&var1, &var2)` will only store "A" and "1" in var1 and var2 respectively.

Hence `fmt.Scanln(a ...interface{})` is a good fit when you know the number of variables coming in, otherwise `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)` might be a better fit.